# Filter a queryset by checking only a portion

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to filter this queryset if it contains 0.5 only on the first row.
As a example bellow first set is a true and second one is a false.

```
 1. ('1. First row (0.5)\n2. Second row (0.5)\n3. Third row (0.69)\n4.
    Fifth row(0.67)\n5. Sixth row(0.66)',)

 2. ('1. First row (0.76)\n2. Second row (0.5)\n3. Third row (0.69)\n4.
    Fifth row(0.67)\n5. Sixth row(0.66)',)
```

I tried this query but it makes second example also a true.

```
queryset = queryset.filter(value__regex = r"\A.*", value__contains='(0.5')
```

how can I check only a portion of the value?

Comment: Just as a heads up (maybe you know already): the syntax of the [`regex` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#regex) depends on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines are always terminated by `\n` and the second row always starts with `2.`, you could try something like this:

```
search_term = '(0.5)\n2.'
qs = qs.filter(value__contains=search_term)
```

Comment: This is good point, though (0.5)\n2 not always in line. sorry for the confusion. it might have  (0.50)\n2 too. I should update the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to slice the string first, get the first row, then query it using contains. Django has [Substr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#substr) function. Here is the example.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Substr 
queryset.filter(alias=Substr('first_row', 1, 15), first_row__contains='(0.5'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should change your regexp, try this:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(value__regex = '^([^\\n]+\(0\.5.*?)\\n')
```